# jack fails to connect to session bus (without error)

Tags: audio, headless

I try to run jack on a headless machine - I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo jackd -dalsa -r44100 -p512
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2014 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Failed to connect to session bus for device reservation /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The standard Jack package is not meant to run headless, and among other things requires dbus. You can build your own Jack to fix this. I suggest you read up on [this page](http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/raspberrypi) on how to install a patched Jack.